# I am trying to use matplotlib with IPython, but get no output

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am trying to use matplotlib through IPython, here is my code:

```
In [9]: import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: x=np.linspace(0,10,100)

In [12]: y=x**2

In [13]: mp.pyplot.plot(x,y)
Out[13]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f7dad912ad0>]
```

The code thus seems to be working, but the graph does not appear anywhere.

I am running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show it:

```
pp.show()
```